# Solve this equation : $\tan^{-1} \frac{x+1}{x-1} + \tan^{-1} \frac{x-1}{x} = \tan^{-1} (-7)$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve this equation : $\tan^{-1} \frac{x+1}{x-1} + \tan^{-1} \frac{x-1}{x} = \tan^{-1} (-7)$

This was an exam question, my try was as follows:

$$ \tan^{-1} \frac{x+1}{x-1} = \tan^{-1} (-7) - \tan^{-1} \frac{x-1}{x} $$

Now, assuming that $x = \tan x $ and substituting that in the above equation so that the equation changes and the $\tan^{-1} \frac{x-1}{x}$ vanishes, but, there is also one tan inverse function, so how to remove it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why assume $x = \tan x$? You'll lose almost all possible solutions if you do that. I'm also unsure how you'd use this assumption.

Comment: Your equation is $tan^{-1}$ for the second tan, right? Please correct the equation

Comment: @Toby yep. sorry...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take tangents on the both sides, you'll get:

$$ \dfrac{\tan \left [ \tan^{-1} \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right] + \tan \left [ \tan^{-1} \frac{x-1}{x} \right]}{ 1 - \tan \left [ \tan^{-1} \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right] \tan \left [ \tan^{-1} \frac{x-1}{x}  \right]} = -7 $$
$$ \frac{2x^2 - x + 1}{1-x} = -7 $$

Upon solving that equation, you'll get $x=2 \blacksquare$

PS: I used Wolframalpha to solve that equation, you may manually do it.

**Note: I changed the question a bit, because I think that your question title is a bit incorrect, this question is example 6 of SL Loney's Inverse Trig Function**

Comment: Sorry, please comment here before you downvote my answer, I've changed the question a bit.

Comment: @Aditya Okay sir, Since the question was about Trigonometry, I've tried to show the important trigonometry steps, rest algebra is quite elementary, so, I guess it'd be fine to skip... Thanks for the suggestion, would keep that in mind in my future answers :)

Comment: In fact, the equation has no solutions. The solution $x=2$ needs to be checked because the two sides of the equation might differ by a multiple of $\pi$. That's the case here.